# FlutterView: AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior

Tags: android, flutter

We are deciding if we want to introduce  [Flutter](https://flutter.io/) into our existing app.
Therefore we are doing some proof of concepts.

Currently we have a native Android app with a CoordinatorLayout that slides away the Toolbar when the RecyclerView content has been scrolled.

Similar to this:

[image: Collapsing toolbar layout]

The idea is to only substitute the [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView) (Android) with a [ListView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) (Flutter).
However this breaks the CollapsingToolbar effect.

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ScrollingActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:id="@+id/someContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Kotlin

```
class ScrollingActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
            replace(R.id.someContainer, Flutter.createFragment("route1"))
        }.commit()
    }
}
```

Flutter

```
void main() => runApp(_widgetForRoute(window.defaultRouteName));

Widget _widgetForRoute(String route) {
  return MediaQuery(
    data: MediaQueryData.fromWindow(window),
    child: Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      child: Material(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text("index $index"),
          itemCount: 100,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Anybody any idea how we can resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need `CustomScrollView`. To give you an idea.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return CustomScrollView(
    slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverAppBar(
        flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(...),
      ),
      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((BuildContext context, int index) {
            return YourWidget();
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: This is how you would implement this when working only in Flutter I'm looking for the hybrid (native + flutter) solution